# Modeling a non-primary Key relationship

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-modeling

I am trying to model the following relationship with the intent of designing classes for EF code first.

`Program` table:

```
ProgramID - PK  
ProgramName  
ClusterCode
```

Sample data

```
ProgramID   ProgramName   ClusterCode  
--------------------------------------
    1       Spring            A  
    2       Fall              A  
    3       Winter            B  
    4       Summer            B
```

`Cluster` table:

```
ID  
ClusterCode  
ClusterDetails
```

Sample data:

```
ID   ClusterCode   ClusterDetails
---------------------------------
 1       A              10  
 2       A              20  
 3       A              30  
 4       B              20  
 5       B              40
```

I need to join the `Program` table to the `Cluster` table so I can get the list of cluster details for each program.

The SQL would be

```
Select   
from Programs P
Join Cluster C On P.ClusterCode = C.ClusterCode  
Where P.ProgramID = 'xxx'
```

Note that for the `Program` table, `ClusteCode` is not unique.

For `Cluster` table, neither `ClusterCode` nor `ClusterDetail` is unique.

How would I model this so I can take advantage of navigation properties and code-first?

Comment: please add the language tag (C# or VB.NET or ets) also it's better to show the classes of mapped above 2 tables

Comment: So this won't answer your question, but this seems like more of a database design problem, not something to be solved with EF. Why not replace the Program table's ClusterCode field with a ClusterID field, as a foreign key into the Cluster table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have mapped above two tables and make an association between them and you are using `C#`, you can use a simple `join` :

```
List<Sting> clustedDets=new ArrayList<String>(); 

var q = 
    from p in ClusterTable
    join c in Program on p equals c.ClusterTable
    select new { p.ClusterDetails }; 

foreach (var v in q) 
{ 
    clustedDets.Add(v.ClusterDetails);  
}
```

Comment: Ok, but is there no way to model this to take advantage of Navigation properties?

Comment: as I don't see any PK/FK relation between your tables and also any association based on it between your entities so It's really hard to use Navigation properties, also I'm not sure my linq query will work or not if not so you have to change it a little on base of how you can make a relation between the entities, good luck.

Comment: It looks like this will need to be the way to go.  I am new to EF and Code first and was trying to figure out if this was possible.  Thanks for the help.